# how to divide the html page to 2 static div and 1 scrollable div?

Tags: html, css, layout

I need to divide my html page using css to 3 vertical columns (left, center, right). The left and right side should be static (not scrollable) and fit the browser height. The center div should be fit to the content and scrollable. Like in the picture below. How I can do this by css?

[image]

Html code:

```
    <body>
      <div id="wrapper">
        <div id="left" >First</div>
        <div id="center" >Second</div>
        <div id="right" >Third</div>
      </div>
   </body>
```

CSS code:

```
    body{
    width: 100%;
    height:100%;
}

#wrapper{
    width: 100%;
    background-color:pink;
    display: flex;
}

#left{
     flex: 1;    
     background-color:#F6070B;
}

#center {
     flex: 3;
     background-color: #0622F4;
}

#right{
    flex: 1;
    background-color: #FAF000;
}
```

Comment: Where would you like the scroll bar to appear for the middle panel, to the right of the middle panel or on the window itself?

Answer (score 0):

Try this code, working perfectly.

**CSS** File

```
#wrapper{

    background-color:pink;
    display: flex;
}

#left{
     flex: 1; 
     left:0;
     width:150px;    
     background-color:#F6070B;
     height:100vh;
     position:fixed;
     top:0;
}

#center {
     margin-left:180px;
     margin-right: 180px;
     flex: 3;
     background-color: lightblue;

}

#right{
    width:150px;
    right:0;
    height:100vh;
    position:fixed;
    top:0;
    background-color: #FAF000;
}
```

**HTML CODE**

```
    <body>
      <div id="wrapper">
        <div id="left" >First</div>
        <div id="center" >
        <script>
        for(i=0; i< 100; i++){
        document.write("Dummy Text<br/>");
        }
        </script>
        </div>
        <div id="right" >Third</div>
      </div>
   </body>
```